# The terminal is freaking out with my .sh character encoding. What can I do?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I have this SH file:

```
echo "KILLING OLD SERVER SESSION"
kill $(cat lastPID.txt)
sleep 10
echo "STARTING SERVER..."
java -jar my.cute.little.server.jar </dev/null>/dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > lastPID.txt
echo "SERVER STARTED! PID:" $(cat lastPID.txt)
```

This creates a new process, stores it's PID in a txt file, so that later it can close it before launching other process. The code works, that is not the problem.

The issue is that when I copy it from my PC to the server (using filezilla) and I run it I get the following:

```
KILLING OLD SERVER SESSION
restart_server.sh: 2: kill: Illegal number:
sleep: invalid time interval `10\r'
Try `sleep --help' for more information.
STARTING SERVER...
: not foundver.sh: 5: restart_server.sh:
SERVER STARTED! PID:
```

Notepad++ states I am using UTF-8 w/o BOM:

[image]

```
$ file restart_server.sh
restart_server.sh: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ file --mime-encoding restart_server.sh
restart_server.sh: us-ascii
```

So, for which sin am I being punished here? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Many syntax errors, not character encoding. check your usage of `sleep` for one, backticks return the output of executing a command, are not a synonym for double quotes.

Comment: I tried adding ", ', and finally ` as a way to bypass this encoding error, I forgot to take them out as I was writing here. The encoding error persists after this removal, as the quotes were not the cause. I have updated the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticks are not string quotes. They run their contents as a command and then replace themselves with the output. You want single quotes or double quotes for strings.

So

```
sleep `10`
```

is erroring because `10` is not a command and then `sleep` gets no argument, etc.

Similarly

```
echo `$! > lastPID.txt`
```

is trying to run `$! > lastPID.txt` as a command which will create an empty `lastPID.txt` file and then error because the pid is not a command. Then `echo` will `echo` the empty string.

You want any of

```
sleep 10
sleep '10'
sleep "10"
```

and

```
echo "$!" > lastPID.txt
```

Among other similar changes.

You also need to save the file with Unix newlines (and not DOS line endings). The encoding itself doesn't matter as much (though UTF-8 is generally a good choice) but you **do not** want a BOM.

Comment: I tried adding ", ', and finally ` as a way to bypass this encoding error, I forgot to take them out as I was writing here. The encoding error persists after this removal, as the quotes were not the cause. I have updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Editing the question just invalidated a large part of my answer but not the part at the end that you still need to deal with. `\r` is DOS line endings. So is the confused error messages (they are overwriting themselves because of the `\r` characters) and the `kill` error is because, presumably, the file doesn't have any contents at that point and/or the job is already dead (you should check for that and for the pid actually being the process you think it is).